# por que cuando hago el strpos() en una cadena me sale un indice y cuando haga la condicional para ese indice me sale false

Tags: php

```
$resultado_marca = strpos($products->MARCA,$palabras[$i]);
if (!is_numeric($resultado_marca)){ 
return "mensaje"  
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias elaborar mucho mejor tu pregunta, agrega el contexto, y agrega ejemplos.. por lo pronto, no se te puede decir mucho porque no sabemos que pasa con ese codigo.

Comment: Ese condicional claro que te da false, estas haciendo un distinto de numérico, pero un indice es numérico, luego el condicional es false. Nunca imprime mensaje en ese caso

Comment: _strpos_ devuelve falso si no se encontró la cadena o un índice numérico, a partir de cero. Entonces, mejor compara si el valor es falso `if($resultado_marca === false) { return 'No encontrado'; }`